# How to trim a string and store residue in a array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, .net-2.0

I'm stuck. (got a thinking barrier right now) :/

I need a stringarray from a string which contaions a lot of "sometext\n\t\t\t\t00:00\n\t\t\t\t05:32\n\t\t\t\t...."
There are always 8 values in this string. I want each (of these 8 ) values in the array[8].
But most importantly are the value. (the text at the beginning is unnecessary).

Comment: I dunno how to set up this code ?! :/

Comment: c#.. sorry I forgot to name it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work:

```
 var source = "sometext\n\t\t\t\t00:00\n\t\t\t\t05:32\n\t\t\t\t...."
 var result = source.Split(new []{"\n\t\t\t\t"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

that is: guessing that all your values are separated by that newline+4 tabs.

If that is not (always) the separator, then you need to specify how to identify a "value" from a "separator".

Comment: `source.Split("\n\t\t\t\t");` does not work like this. you can only split (one) char(s). So i'll will get a huge array [451] as result. The separator should always be the same. (mine just contains more \t).

Comment: I used `var result = source.Split(new Char[] { '\n', '\t', });`

Comment: @user1559441 - I corrected my example, this now works. Your example splits on any `\n` or `\t`, so it returns a lot of empty values.

Comment: true, and it's a bad solution with all the empty values. Your example returns one array with the first part of the string. '"Total Time\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t00:00"'.. Btw. I took a quick look on the string(source). The first "\n\t\t\t.." is shorter then the other 6(same length). I'm trying `string s = myString.Replace("\t", "");` The result is alright to most of my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will do what you need

```
 int i,j;
 int[] array=new int[8];
 string s="sometext\n\t\t\t\t00:00\n\t\t\t\t05:32\n\t\t\t\t...."; // or input something
 for(i=j=0;i<s.Length;i++){
    if (s[i]>='0'&&s[i]<='9'){
       array[j++]=s[i]-'0';
    }
 }
```

Comment: Cannot implicity convert type 'string' to char?!
May I just use a string instead?

Comment: of course you can use string. as you are asking for code in c#, I just updated the code from c++ to c#